# Is $c^{\dagger}|\psi_N \rangle= \sqrt{N+1}| \psi_N \rangle $ or $c^{\dagger}|\psi_N \rangle= | \psi_{N+1} \rangle $ in case of fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle

For the $N$ fermion state, when we apply creation operator $c^{\dagger}$, should we write the factor $\sqrt{N+1}$ with the resultant state, like $c^{\dagger}|\psi_N \rangle= \sqrt{N+1}| \psi_N \rangle .$

Answer (score 9):

There is no $N$-fermion state except for $N=0$ or $N=1$, so you only really need two rules:

$$c^\dagger |\psi_0\rangle = |\psi_1\rangle$$

$$c^\dagger |\psi_1\rangle = 0$$

Comment: These two rules can be summarized into one: 
$c^{\dagger}|\psi_N \rangle= \sqrt{1-N}| \psi_{1-N} \rangle$

Comment: @ThomasFritsch or $(1-N)$ for that matter.

Comment: @Javier Here fermionic N state means N number of fermions present in N different states, $|\psi_N\rangle = |n_1,n_2, n_3......,n_N \rangle$

Comment: @Tooba If you create a fermion in a *different* state, which is not yet occupied by any of the other N fermions, you don't need any $\sqrt{N+1}$ factor. But note: if you create a boson in a state which is not yet occupied by any other boson, you don't get any such factor either.